# PL/SQL Assign number on each iteration

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I'm trying to assign a value for each one of my items. These are my columns:

Manager_id = contains a changing number of managers
Sales_reps = list of the reps under the managers

What I'm trying to do is to loop throught every manager and assign a value (starting with 1) to each rep under it, like this:

```
Manager_1:
Rep_1
Rep_2

Manager_2:
Rep_1
Rep_2
Rep_3
Rep_4

Manager_3:
Rep_1
Rep_2
```

Etc.

I've tried basic loops, for loops, associative arrays but nothing seems to work.
Could someone give me a hand please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] including: **YOUR** attempt(s) at solving the problem; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statement for the sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a nested loops issue. Something like this:

```
begin
  for cur_m in (select manager_id, manager_name, rownum rn from managers) 
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_m.manager_name ||'_'|| cur_m.rn);

    for cur_e in (select employee_name, rownum rn from employees
                  where manager_id = cur_m.manager_id
                 )
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(cur_e.employee_name || cur_e.rn);
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

---

To answer question you posted as a comment: if you want to restart sequence per each manager, change the inner loop to

```
    for cur_e in (select employee_name, 
                    row_number() over (partition by manager_id order by employee_name) rn 
                  from employees
                  where manager_id = cur_m.manager_id
                 )
```

Comment: Typo `cur_r` for `cur_m`

Comment: Yes, there was. Thank you, @Suresh.

Comment: Thank you!
Can I bother you one last time please?
This works but...is it possible to reset the numbers for each manager?
For example:
Manager 1 = Rep 1 / Rep 2
Manager 2 = (the count re-starts for this manager) Rep 1 / Rep 2 / Rep 3 / Rep 4
Something like that? to set the count back to 1 for each Manager?
Thank you for helping me out, you rock

Comment: You're welcome. I posted some more info at the bottom of the answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you! Could I bother you one last time please? Sorry.
My Rep column repeats the same name several times (Rep ABC is shown X amount of times cause of the data included on the original table) so the end result of the query you provided (thank you again) shows the higher number for that Rep. E.g.
Manager 1 = Rep ABC # 6 / Rep XYZ # 3 (first rep is listed on 3 rows and second is listed on 6 rows on the original table).
Is there a way to only get the first (lowest) number for each one?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what that means. "Lowest number" looks like MIN function could help. Or perhaps DISTINCT? Can't tell. It would have been easier if you posted the question so that it reflects what you really have.

Comment: Thank you LittleFoot, I was able to figure it out (obviously based on your query).
I would hug you if I could. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you made it work :)